# OpenCV Median Filter for double Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, median

I'am using OpenCV in a C++ project. I have obtained a depthmap from a stereovision camera and would like to filter it with a median filter. My Depthmap is a `cv::Mat_< double>`. (I can not change the format, only can convert it).

Is there a possibility to achieve the functionality of the median filter for a `cv::Mat_< double>` input?

```
medianBlur(cv::Mat_<double> src, cv::Mat_<double> dst, int ksize)
```

In the documentation I only found support for `CV_8U`, `CV_16U`, or `CV_32F` images.
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur

Is there a solution for my problem availible in the OpenCV library.
Should I make my own median filter? If I have to, do you have any good reference?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
cv::Mat_<double> input;
cv::Mat_<double> output; // or  cv::Mat output;
cv::medianBlur(input, output, 3);
```

PS: you have to make sure that `int ksize` can only be 3 or 5 for your input (double mat). As said in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur):

> Parameters:
>   **`src`** – input 1-, 3-, or 4-channel image; **when `ksize` is 3 or 5, the image depth should be `CV_8U, CV_16U`, or `CV_32F`, for larger aperture sizes, it can only be `CV_8U`.**
>
> ...
>
> **`ksize`** – aperture linear size; **it must be odd and greater than 1, for example: 3, 5, 7 ...**

Answer (score 2):

can used and cv::UMat for operate with OpenCL/CUDA

```
cv::UMat input;
cv::UMat output;
```

for ksize >5

```
    cv::UMat tmp;
    if (ksize>5){
        switch (input.type()) {
        case CV_16UC1:
        case CV_16UC3:
        case CV_16UC4:
            input.convertTo(tmp,CV_8U,1./255.);
            break;
        case CV_32FC1:
        case CV_32FC3:
        case CV_32FC4:
            input.convertTo(tmp,CV_8U,255.);
            break;
        default:
            input.assignTo(tmp);
            break;
        }
    }else{
        input.assignTo(tmp);
    }
    try{
      cv::medianBlur(tmp, output, ksize);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& ex) {
      qWarning()<<"medianBlurImage error"<<ex.what();
    }
```